# Change the number of workspaces with keyboard

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I tend to "mistype" a lot when, for instance, in emacs or such. And by some unfortunate coincidence, I happen to change quite often the number of workspaces in xubuntu, and I end up reorganizing all windows and stuff again and again. It should be a combination of keys close to a common I use, but I couldn't find it so far.

**Which combination of keys change the number of active workspaces in xubuntu?**

and

**How do I disable it?**

Answer (score 1):

You can see a list of all the shortcuts of Xubuntu from **System Settings** > **Keyboard** then switch to **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab and then you will be able, beyond to see all of them, to change them and create new shortcuts.

For **workspaces** got to **Navigation** and change the shortcuts as desired.

Comment: There is no `Keyboard Shortcuts`, but `Application Shortcuts` in the keyboard dialog in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The keys that delete workspaces are <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. I mistype a lot when aiming for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in emacs.

I found them in `Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard`:

[image]